# SP13 - Create Content types for Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-type

I want to create content type with field for new Pagelayout(Created by Design Manager). My question is what is a  :

**Select parent content type from:** 
List Content Types **or** Page Layout Content Types

**Parent Content Type must be a ?**

[image]

Comment: Please refer this link: http://blog.navantis.com/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Parent Content type From" should be **Publishing Content Type**.

And then select **Page**.

This article may give you more info:- http://blog.navantis.com/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Where I create a page layout for Master page, i have two option - seattle and oslo. Which to choose?

Comment: You can choose any one of them. Both are compatible with just minor design changes